# Getting different user IDs for one facebook user within one facebook-App?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm programming a facebook app within a user can invite friends by

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});`
```

The ID of the current user I get by

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
        console.log(response.authResponse.userID);
    });

    FB.init({
        appId      : **************,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : false,
        version    : 'v2.0',
        status     : true
    });
}
```

I allways save the own userID and user name together with all IDs which the user had invite. When an invited user logg in to the app, this invited user should see the friends name the invitation comes from.

I thought this is easy because I thought the userIDs are allways the same with in the app-scope. And for the most users the app works correct. But for one of the app-testers (real existing fb-user with role "administrator" - not just a created test-user) there are two diffrent IDs. When the user itself is logged in, the ID is different to the ID which is returned when an other user invites him.

the apprequests method returns the first of the following IDs and the statusChange the second:

```
102048*****482880
102048*****482879
```

You can see, the IDs are very similar to each other but not the same (just +1). Whats the reason? This problem have only one of multiple test-users. Any ideas?

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve my problem now:

I had an additional code in my javascript file where the user id was accidentally used as an integer instead as a string. Javascript have problems with very large integers, so it was a rounding problem.

So the solution is to always use string type for the id.